# Reversing addition of numbers from sorted array into smaller arrays at every other iteration

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an **array** that I need to **sort**, and then **split** them into **smaller arrays** where the **addition of the numbers to the smaller arrays are reversed at every other iteration**. I would want to be able to choose how many numbers fit into each smaller array, and how many smaller arrays there are.

An example would be:

numbersArr = [10, 5, 13, 25, 30, 2, 18, 11, 22]

sortedNumbersArr =  [2, 5, 10, 11, 13, 18, 22, 25, 30]

avgOfSortedNumbers = **15**

smallerArrs = [[ 10, 11, 30 ], [ 5, 13, 25 ], [ 2, 18, 22 ]]

avgOfSmallArrs =  **17**            **14**             **14**

You can see that at every even iteration,the addition of numbers from the sortedNumbersArr switches

switched -> not switched -> switched

[10, 5, 2] -> [11, 13, 18] -> [30, 25, 22]

I am doing this so that the average isn't extreme on both ends.

The problem is that the code works for when I want 3 smaller arrays and 3 values in each smaller array. If I try changing this to 5 smaller arrays and 2 values in each for example (we would need to add more numbers to the sortedNumbersArr so there are enough values), I get weird results where there are empty values being added and other smaller arrays that are empty.

sortedNumbersArr =  [2, 5, 10, 11, 13, 15, 18, 22, 25, 30]

numInsideSmallerArr = 2;

numOfSmallerArr = 5;

smallerArrs = [[ <1 empty item>, 10, <1 empty item>, 18 ], [ <1 empty item>, 11, <1 empty item>, 22 ], [], [ 5, <1 empty item>, 15, <1 empty item>, 30 ], [ 2, <1 empty item>, 13, <1 empty item>, 25 ]]

avgOfSmallArrs = **15**, **17**, **NaN**, **17**, **13**

My current code looks something like this:

```js
// variables to determine resulting array size and how many values it holds 
let numInsideSmallerArr = 3; 

let numOfSmallerArr = 3; 

let sortedNumbersArr = [2, 5, 10, 11, 13, 18, 22, 25, 30]; 

// variable that holds the resulting sorted/split array 

let smallerArrList = []; 

let indxA = 0; 

// temp variable used to reverse the order 
let smallerArrIndex; 

// populates the number of smaller empty arrays so values can be added to it 
for (let i = 0; i < numOfSmallerArr ; i++) { 
  smallerArrList[i] = []; 
} 

// loop through the smaller arrays 
for (let i = 0; i < numOfSmallerArr; i++) { 
  // loop through the smaller array 
  for (let j = 0; j < numInsideSmallerArr; j++) {
  
  smallerArrIndex = j; 
  
  // reverse order at every even iteration 
  if (i%2 === 0) { 
  smallerArrIndex = numOfSmallerArr - 1 - j;
  } 
  
  // add number to the smaller indexes in small array list 
  smallerArrList[smallerArrIndex][i]= sortedNumbersArr[indxA]; 
  indxA++; 
  }
}
  
console.log(smallerArrList)
```

I started to program pretty recently and am currently learning data structures and algorithms so I wasn't sure if one already exists for what I am trying to do. Could anyone point me in the right direction of where my logic is incorrect? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Regarding: _"I am doing this so that the average isn't extreme on both ends"_ -- please explain what you mean. Are you trying to remove outliers from a sample? The average of the entire array and the average-of-averages of smaller arrays will be the same. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Hey,

What I meant by that was that if we always gave the numbers in the same order, the arrays that are indexed at later values will always have the largest of the numbers available.

I wanted to make the order switch so that it would prevent that in some sense.

Let's say you need to split [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] into 3 arrays

[1,4,7],[2,5,8].[3,6,9]

avg = 4, 5, 6

I would prefer to have 

[3,4,9]. [2,5,8], [1,6,7]

avg = 5.3, 5, 4.6

Hopefully that explanation was a bit better!

Comment: Okay, but why do you need it? What will you do with it? Now you're not even talking about averages. It sounds like you're trying to partition your data or maybe you're looking for the kind of functionality provided by a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).

Comment: What I need this for is that I am trying to come up with a simple matchmaking system.

If you think of those values as numbers of games played, I want a player list divided into more even teams where the averages are a bit more spread out.

Is the heap what I am looking for? I haven't quite gotten there yet in my studies so I'm not too sure how to implement it but I can look into it for sure!

Comment: Essentially you're trying to find a combination of sets with equal number of players, roughly the same spread of values (max - min), and the same average skill. This is an optimization problem that you're unlikely to solve by arbitrarily swapping and sorting. Look up _dynamic programming_.

Comment: Oh goodness, that sounds like it might be a bit over my head. Here I thought I was super close to having solved the problem.

Thanks so much for your help paddy! I'm going to have to look into dynamic programming a bit before I am able to implement an optimization for this problem. I thought it might be a bit easier but I guess that was me thinking of it a bit too lightly.

Comment: Well, I could be overthinking it too. In the end, only you know the full constraints of the problem and its requirements. I'm sure there is an entire class of problems related to matchmaking, especially when it comes to avoiding repeatedly matching the same players against eachother. And I'm sure it boils down to part science, part math, and part black magic.

Comment: Yeah, I may have been oversimplifying the problem. I thought if I could get a decent algorithm set up that does what I wanted, it would be applicable as a way to match make. I'll definitely have to keep studying this since there are a ton of things that go into this. Thanks so much for your help paddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't really understand the logic you tried to implement **in the code** where you let the index `indxA` traverse the source array from left to right. This follows a different procedure than you described. In the description you explain how one subarray is formed by selecting some particular indices in the source array.

I would work in the following order of actions: create each sub array one after the other completely: so first finish the first sub array (using the logic you described), then the second, ...etc.

Then the alteration formula you used will work well:

```js
function spread(numbers, chunkSize) {
    const length = Math.ceil(numbers.length / chunkSize);
    const result = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        const chunk = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++) {
            // Alteration
            let source = i * length + (i % 2 ? length - 1 - j : j);
            if (source >= numbers.length) break;
            chunk.push(numbers[source]);
        }
        result.push(chunk);
    }
    return result;
}

// Example run
const sortedNumbersArr = [2, 5, 10, 11, 13, 15, 18, 22, 25, 30, 34, 36]
const numInsideSmallerArr = 3;
const result = spread(sortedNumbersArr, numInsideSmallerArr);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for your help. 

Honestly with my limited knowledge of what I knew, I was just trying to distribute the sortedNumbersArr as evenly (in terms of their averages) into the breakdown that I wanted (numInsideSmallerArr).


The code you have definitely allows for this to happen so thank you so much! I will have to keep studying and change parameters but this is a great start in terms of what I was needing.

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple solution, using [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library:

```
import {pipe, page, map} from 'iter-ops';

const input = [10, 5, 13, 25, 30, 2, 18, 11, 22];

const i = pipe(
    input.sort((a, b) => a - b), // sort all elements
    page(3), // split into 3-element pages
    map(a => a.sort((a, b) => b - a)) // reverse-sort elements in pages
); //=> Iterable<number[]>

console.log(...i); //=> [ 10, 5, 2 ] [ 18, 13, 11 ] [ 30, 25, 22 ]
```

P.S. I do development for `iter-ops`, in case you need further assistance ;)

Comment: Can I humbly suggest that if you're suggesting a library you help maintain that you add a disclaimer to your answer?  I do something like "Using [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com) (note: I'm a principal developer of Ramda) you can do..."

Comment: Thanks for this! I actually ended up using a part of the solution from trincot, but I'll keep this in mind if I want to use a library!